# Prevent init.py from calling twice

Tags: python

I have a project structure which looks like the following:

```
projects
    __init__.py
    project_a
    project_b
```

In the **init**.py, I iterate through the projects and i import those modules via `import projects.project_a` etc. We then add the module say `ProjectA` into a global variable stored in `__init__.py`. The problem is that when I do

`import projects`, it attempts to run `import projects.project_a` which then calls the `__init__.py` in `projects`, wiping out the global variable. I don't know how to get around this

Comment: What makes `import projects.project_a` run `projects/__init__.py` a second time? Do you have a specific example that can reproduce the behaviour you are describing?

Comment: Are you perhaps running into the issue that `global` does not span across modules?

Comment: It looks like this is happening inside of my bazel build environment, and not regular python